# QT: How to replace number (Start, End) in a JSON from server

Tags: c++, arrays, json, qt, qt-creator

This is how my JSON file looks like. As you can see, the start_x, start_y, and end_x, end_y, degree_of_rotation is a number.

```
{
    "ID" : "ROLL1",
"action" : "start",
  "zone" :
    {
        "start_x" : 0,
        "start_y" : 4,

        "end_x" : 10,
        "end_y" : 5,

    "motion" :
    {
        "motion_type": "xxxxxx",
        "degree_of_rotation": 30,
        "rotation_direction": "yyyyyy",
        "linear_direction": "+ve"
    }
    }
}
```

How can I replace and save the number in JSON from the server? Currently, this is what I have. Qt5 has a new JSON parser and I want to use it. The problem is that it isn't too clear about what the functions do

```
void JsonFileread::Json_File_Function()
{
    try
    {
        qDebug() <<"file reading";

        file.setFileName("/home/JSON/jsonfile.js");   
        file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);

        QFileDevice::FileError err = QFileDevice::NoError;

        if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        {
            qDebug() <<"Could not open file : "<<file.fileName() <<"for reading :"<<file.errorString()<<endl;
            errMsg =file.errorString();
            err =file.error();
            cout<<"err : "<<err<<endl;
        }

        settings = file.readAll(); 

        if (file.error() != QFile::NoError) {
               qDebug() << QString("Failed to read from file %1, error: %2").arg(file.fileName()).arg(file.errorString());
           }

        if (settings.isEmpty()) {
                qDebug() << "No data was currently available for reading from file" << file.fileName();
            }

        file.close();

        object = EchoClient::jsonstringflag;

        QJsonDocument sd = QJsonDocument::fromJson(settings.toUtf8()); 
        QJsonObject sett2 = sd.object(); 

        QJsonValue mainid = sett2["ID"];
        mainid = mainid.toString();

        QJsonValue action = sett2["action"];
        actionstring = action.toString();

        QJsonValue value = sett2.value(QString("zone")); 
        QJsonObject item = value.toObject();

        QJsonValue startx = item["start_x"]; 
        startvaluex = startx.toInt();

        QJsonValue starty = item["start_y"];
        startvaluey = starty.toInt();

        QJsonValue endx = item["end_x"]; 
        endvaluex = endx.toInt();

        xendvaluestring = endx.toString();
        qWarning() << endvaluex<<endl;

        QJsonValue endy = item["end_y"]; 
        endvaluey = endy.toInt();

        yendvaluestring = endy.toString();
        qWarning() << endvaluey<<endl;

        QJsonValue motion = item.value(QString("motion"));
        QJsonObject motion_object = motion.toObject();

        QJsonValue motiontype = motion_object["motion_type"];
        motiontypestring = motiontype.toString();

        QJsonValue directionlinear = motion_object["linear_direction"];
        lineardirection = directionlinear.toString();

        QJsonValue rotatingangle = motion_object["degree_of_rotation"];
        angleofrotation = rotatingangle.toInt();
    }

    catch (QJsonParseError error)
        {
            qDebug() <<  error.errorString();
        }
    catch(...)
        {
            qDebug() <<  "due to some other error";
        }
}
```

So help to solve the problem

Comment: Your code snippet seems to be only about reading values, where exactly are you trying to set/change values?
Also: if `settings` is intended to be passed to the JSON Parser, make it a `QByteArray`. Using a `QString` needlessly requires conversion from and back again to UTF-8

Comment: @Kevin Krammer thanks for your valuable response. Ya exactly, this is only about reading JSON values, I don't know how to change or replace, For example, consider the above code, reading the ''start_x, start_y, and end_x, end_y'' then this value sent to the server. Now, I have received the value from the server, but whenever we received ''start_x, start_y, and end_x, end_y" value, JSON value should change or replace according to that value. Ex: ('Startx 0 replace5 (startx 5), starty 4 to starty 7' ). Is it possible ? I don't know how to change.

Comment: Receive JSON data from server to client, received value will replace to JSON each and every time

Answer (score 0):

You can write to a `QJsonObject` very similar to how you read its properties

```
QJsonObject obj;
obj["key"] = value;
```

Once you have built the `QJsonObject` tree, set the top level element on a `QJsonDocument` and use it to generate the JSON content.

Comment: If I will use similar manner, that will replace the values in JSON file? Example for obj["key"] = value; ?

Comment: You can modify the objects that you get from the file and then write the new JSON to the file.